# Ignore Full File Path with sed command

Tags: shell

I have 2 log files which contains absolute path of text files like:

```
***FileName: /usr/abc/1.txt
***FileName: /usr/cde/1.txt
```

How to use "sed" to replace the full path with only file name ?

Like:  ***FileName: /usr/abc/1.txt   --> ***FileName: 1.txt

I a using this: sed -f  s/^.*1.txt/1.txt/ , but with this i get :

***FileName: /usr/abc/1.txt  --> 1.txt

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in form of code,could you please do mention your samples more clearly(wrapping them in CODE TAGS) in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

From your --> notation, I think you want *everything* on the line except the leading pathname.  If correct, this should work:

```
sed 's:/.*/::' < logfile
```

or possibly:

```
cat logfile1 logfile2 | sed 's:/.*/::'
```

Comment: No, i think a more specific pattern I need, because it is replacing other lines where I have '/'